# Bindings in nested WPF DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have some WPF control called Foo. Grid structure with DevExpress LoadingDecorator looks like that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <dx:LoadingDecorator Name="Decorator" IsSplashScreenShown="{Binding Path=ShowLoader}" SplashScreenLocation="CenterWindow">
            <dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <dx:WaitIndicator DeferedVisibility="True">
                        <dx:WaitIndicator.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Operation:" FontSize="15"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CurrLoadStat}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </dx:WaitIndicator.ContentTemplate>
                    </dx:WaitIndicator>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dx:LoadingDecorator.SplashScreenTemplate>
        </dx:LoadingDecorator>
    </StackPanel>

    ...

</Grid>
```

Base ViewModel class implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface and ViewModel class (FooViewModel) used as DataContext for control with Grid described above inherits from it. I have implemented property to change text property in 2nd TextBlock element:

```
        private string currLoadStat = "Preparing data...";

        public string CurrtLoadStat
        {
            get
            {
                return currLoadStat;
            }
            set
            {
                currLoadStat = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrLoadStat");
            }
        }
```

My problem is that binding instruction doesn't work and I see only text defined in first TextBlock. 
Can You provide me some solution to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property has a "t" in the middle of the name but your binding path (XAML) and magic string you pass to `OnPropertyChanged` do not. The string you pass when you raise the `PropertyChanged` event method must *exactly match* your view model's property name.

If you are using C# 5 or 6 then switch to using one of the approaches [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315621/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-does-a-better-way-exist) and you would eliminate the need for passing magic strings.

Comment: Does the run time output window show a binding error? What if you temporarily change to just `... Text={Binding }`, does anything show up in the Textblock then? That would rule out that the issue is not the Path.

Comment: Error from output window: "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CurrLoadStat' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=-860452824)'. BindingExpression:Path=CurrLoadStat; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-860452824); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')"  . Changing binding to Text={Binding} only gives me text "Loading..." taken from DevExpress properties.

Comment: The output tells you one thing for sure which is that the DataContext or your TextBlock is not an instance of your view model class but rather just a string (set to "Loading..." as you mentioned).

Comment: Yes, DataContext was not properly defined. Thank You for give me right direction of thinking. :)