# Binding a button nested in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, data-binding, datatemplate

I need to bind a button's command inside a datatemplate like below:

```
                      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="-" Cursor="Hand" Width="50"
                                            Background="Red" x:Name="removeButton"
                                            Command="{Binding Remove}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Unfortunately it does not work. How can I bind a command in a button insade a datatemplate?

I found that thread in the forum:

[Bindings in nested WPF DataTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065254/bindings-in-nested-wpf-datatemplates)

but the method given by person, who answered this question, does not work as well. I think, that something has changed in WPF since this time, I would you grateful for your help.

Comment: Where is `Remove` defined?

Comment: @mma8 In the ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Remove` is defined in the view model of the parent `ListView`, you could bind to it using a `RelativeSource`:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.Remove,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
```

You could also set the `AncestorType` to `Window` or `UserControl` depending on where the command property is defined and where the `DataTemplate` is applied.